# Method App\Post::__toString() must not throw an exception error when I try to destroy a post

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am currently using Laravel 5.2.

When I call the destroy method on my Post controller I get the following message:

[image]

I have taken a look at this question because it seems very similar to mine, although the answers were not able to help: [Exception being thrown when trying to delete model in laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679430/exception-being-thrown-when-trying-to-delete-model-in-laravel-5-2)

The answers were not able to help because I am not able to find any folder called Entrust in my project, and editing the line in config/auth only gave me a different error about not being able to find "App\Models\User".

I am not really sure where else to look for this issue and would really appreciate any help or advice you can give.

Here is my destroy method and Post controller:

Post Controller

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table    = 'posts';

    /**
     * Define relationship between posts and categories.
     *
     * @return eloquent relationship
     */
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
    }

    /**
     * Define relationship between posts and tags.
     *
     * @return eloquent relationship
     */
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'post_tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
    }
}
```

Destroy Method

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    //  find the post and tags
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $tags = $post->tags();

    //  update post_tag relationship
    if($tags != null)
    {
        $post->tags()->detach($tags);    
    }

    //  delete the post
    $post->delete();

    //  redirect with flash data to posts.index
    Session::flash('success', 'The blog post was deleted successfully!');
    return redirect()->route('posts.index');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do `Post::find($id)->delete()` instead of `$post->delete()`? I think because you did `$post->tags()->detach($tags)`.. it affected $post variable.

Comment: @Spacemudd The `$post` variable is not affected by detaching relations. _The detach method will remove the appropriate record out of the intermediate table; however, both models will remain in the database_ [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a query builder instance from `$tags = $post->tags();`, instead just do `$tags = $post->tags;` to get the collection.

Second, pass an array of ids to the detach method like so:

```
//  find the post and tags
$post = Post::find($id);
$ids = $post->tags->pluck('id');

//  update post_tag relationship
if(count($ids))
{
    $post->tags()->detach($ids);    
}

//  delete the post
$post->delete();
```